# How to get document fields when a failure happens in an Elasticsearch bulk operation?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently migrating entities from a DBMS to Elasticsearch using bulk requests, but I want to be able to identify which specific entities failed during the operation (without having to query Elastic after the operation).
I noticed the `BulkItemResponse.Failure` class has an `ID_FIELD`, but that seems to be the action, not the document.

Is there any field in the response that I can use to retrieve the fields of the failing documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the Elasticsearch forums, it seems it's only possible to retrieve the index of the document in the bulk request, but not the content of the document
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/way-to-re-index-failed-documents-using-bulkprocessor/33736/3

For the record, this is how I extracted the failing items id from the bulk response:

```
List<Integer> processBulkResponse(BulkResponse bulkResponse) {
    List<Integer> failures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BulkItemResponse bulkItemResponse : bulkResponse) {
        if (bulkItemResponse.isFailed()) {
            failures.add(bulkItemResponse.getItemId());
        }
    }
    return failures;
}
```